# Changing dates based on users timezone?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I wrote this function to change the times displayed on my site based on the users timezone

```
function userTime($time, $timezone) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    return $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}

echo userTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "America/New_ York");
```

The function works but to where it's spitting out a different time from the users actual location, am I doing something wrong or am I missing a step?

Comment: What part of this code would make you think it knows the user's location?  (Also, you have an extraneous space after the underscore in the time zone id).

Comment: That's actually an accidental space from when I typed this post, the code is normal. I use the GeoIP to get the users timezone.

Comment: See the dup post for how to do it.  You need to consider the source time zone, and you need to first create a `DateTime` in that source time zone before calling `setTimezone` to convert it to a different time zone.   Your current code *creates* the value in the destination time zone, rather than converting to it.